# Spring 4 + Spring Batch + Quartz 2.2.x tutorial

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I've been looking for days now for a simple implementation of Spring batch processor with the scheduler (Quartz) but with no luck! all the samples that i laid my hands on were not working or depreciated, my application should provide setting the job firing time **dynamically** (retrieved from Database)

Comment: When job firing time changed in database what do you suppose to do? Quartz job is initialized one time and triggered accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but for me the jobs trigger time can changed during runtime...

Comment: i think what you need is mark it as "every minute". every minute, you run the task. the fist line gets the actual cron expression from the database, 2nd like checks the cron expression against the current time. in an if statement, run the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

try adding below code in spring-quartz.xml file

```
<!--testAlerts cron trigger -->
<bean id="testAlertsTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="name" value="testAlertsTrigger" />
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="testAlertsJobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 4 * * ?" />
</bean>

<!-- scheduler -->
<bean id="schedulerFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="hbnTransactionManager" />
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
              <ref bean="testAlertsTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="commandDispatcher" value-ref="commandDispatcher" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="${QUARTZ.org.quartz.autoStartup}" />
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="${QUARTZ.org.quartz.overwriteExistingJobs}" />
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">${QUARTZ.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">${QUARTZ.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">${QUARTZ.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">${QUARTZ.org.quartz.jobStore.class}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">${QUARTZ.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">${QUARTZ.org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```